# How to setPage() a JEditorPane with a localfile which is outside of the .jar file?

Tags: java, jeditorpane

My program has the following path in the .jar file
`src/test/Program.class`

and my program is as follow...

`Program.java`

```
package test;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.swing.JEditorPane;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Program {

    JEditorPane editorPane;
        public Program() {
        File file = new File("temp.htm");
        try {
            file.createNewFile();
            editorPane = new JEditorPane();
            editorPane.setPage(Program.class.getResource("temp.htm"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public JEditorPane getEditorPane(){
        return editorPane;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(400, 400);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        Program p = new Program();
        frame.getContentPane().add(p.getEditorPane());
    }
}
```

The problem is that I have compiled the program in a `.jar` file.
The `file.createNewFile();` creates the `temp.htm` file outside the `.jar` file
So when `editorPane.setPage(Program.class.getResource("temp.htm"));` is called the file is not found as it searches for file inside the `test` package.
How to `setPage()` the `temp.htm` file whiich is outside the `.jar` file but in the same folder as the `.jar` file?
As the `temp.htm` is a localfile and I want a relative path instead of an absolute path.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like:

```
// get location of the code source
URL url = yourpackage.Main.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation();

try {
    // extract directory from code source url
    String root = (new File(url.toURI())).getParentFile().getPath();
    File doc = new File(root, "test.htm");
    // create htm file contents for testing
    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(doc);
    writer.write("<h1>Test</h1>");
    writer.close();
    // open it in the editor
    editor.setPage(doc.toURI().toURL());
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use a .java-file as the classpath. You can only put paths (relative or absolute) or JAR-files into the classpath. As long as the path where you write the temporary file to is part of the classpath, it should work with

```
editorPane.setPage(Program.class.getResource("temp.htm"));
```

as you wrote.

In other words, before you use

```
file.createNewFile();
```

you need to make sure that `file` is a directory listed in the classpath.

Comment: after I make the .jar file is it possible to create a file in the directory listed in the classpath

Comment: @Jaguar: if you have the access rights to that directory it should work.

Comment: but the directory will not be existing,now only the jar file will be there. and the directory will be in the jar file

Comment: in such a case is it possible to write inside a jar file

Comment: @Jaguar: You want to create a directory in the JAR-file? I don't think that that's going to work as the JVM holds a lock on the JAR-file. You would need to create a directory somewhere in the user's home. That way the chance is higher to avoid access restrictions. After you created the directory you need to create a new `URLClassLoader` with all classpath-entries you need. You can then use that instance to call `getResource()` on it.

Comment: calling this method `file.createNewFile();` will automatically create the `temp.htm` file outside the .jarfile. Now the question is how to use that file (its relative path) in the setPage() method

Comment: @Jaguar: do `file.getParentFile().getAbsolutePath()` and put that into the `URLClassLoader`. Then `editorPane.setPage(Program.class.getResource("temp.htm"));` should work.

Comment: `file.getParentFile().getAbsolutePath()` and put that into the `URLClassLoader`. can you please describe how to implement this.