# Loading html file into JEditorPane

Tags: java, html, swing

Would anyone be able to tell me how I could load a html document into a JEditorPane. I have tried the following which does not seem to work:

```
try{
    URL h = new URL("file://test.html");
    pane.setPage(h); 
} catch (Exception e) {}
```

Comment: That empty catch statement is so dangerous! Don't do that. Print stacktrace or log it somewhere at least. It's probably cause of your problem (you don't know what happened when failed).

Comment: I have now put something in the catch statement so I can see what happens when it fails but the html file is still not loading.

Comment: Besides the sage advice of @Sorceror, I recommend adding the following lines `File f = new File("test.html"); System.out.println(f.exists()); URL h = f.toURI().toURL(); System.out.println(h);..`

Comment: *"I have now.."*  Show us the new code in an [edit to the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/15052690/edit).

Comment: I added the lines of code you suggested and that fixed the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

**Open html file in jeditor pane in java**

```
       JeditorPane editorpane= new JEditorPane();
       editorScrollPane = new JScrollPane(editorpane);
       editorScrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
       File file = new File("F://test.htm");
       editorpane.setPage(file.toURI().toURL());
       editorpane.setEditable(true);
```

Hope this will help you,
  Here this is working

Comment: why we cant add path directly ??

Answer (score 0):

How about using an absolute path? Look at [java.lang.System.getProperties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperties%28%29) and use "user.dir" i.e. to get some absolute path to beef up your file url.

Answer (score 0):

you can follow sun's tutorial on webview tutorial on swing... :) http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/swing/SimpleSwingBrowser.java.htm

I am pasting a source code of their demo.

```
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEvent;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import static javafx.concurrent.Worker.State.FAILED;

public class SimpleSwingBrowser implements Runnable {
    private JFXPanel jfxPanel;
    private WebEngine engine;

    private JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    private JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    private JLabel lblStatus = new JLabel();

    private JButton btnGo = new JButton("Go");
    private JTextField txtURL = new JTextField();
    private JProgressBar progressBar = new JProgressBar();

    private void initComponents() {
        jfxPanel = new JFXPanel();

        createScene();

        ActionListener al = new ActionListener() {
            @Override public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                loadURL(txtURL.getText());
            }
        };

        btnGo.addActionListener(al);
        txtURL.addActionListener(al);

        progressBar.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150, 18));
        progressBar.setStringPainted(true);

        JPanel topBar = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(5, 0));
        topBar.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(3, 5, 3, 5));
        topBar.add(txtURL, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        topBar.add(btnGo, BorderLayout.EAST);


        JPanel statusBar = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(5, 0));
        statusBar.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(3, 5, 3, 5));
        statusBar.add(lblStatus, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        statusBar.add(progressBar, BorderLayout.EAST);

        panel.add(topBar, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        panel.add(jfxPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        panel.add(statusBar, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
    }

    private void createScene() {

        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override public void run() {

                WebView view = new WebView();
                engine = view.getEngine();

                engine.titleProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> observable, String oldValue, final String newValue) {
                        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                            @Override public void run() {
                                frame.setTitle(newValue);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });

                engine.setOnStatusChanged(new EventHandler<WebEvent<String>>() {
                    @Override public void handle(final WebEvent<String> event) {
                        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                            @Override public void run() {
                                lblStatus.setText(event.getData());
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });

                engine.locationProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> ov, String oldValue, final String newValue) {
                        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                            @Override public void run() {
                                txtURL.setText(newValue);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });

                engine.getLoadWorker().workDoneProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {
                    @Override
                    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> observableValue, Number oldValue, final Number newValue) {
                        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                            @Override public void run() {
                                progressBar.setValue(newValue.intValue());
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });

                engine.getLoadWorker()
                        .exceptionProperty()
                        .addListener(new ChangeListener<Throwable>() {

                            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Throwable> o, Throwable old, final Throwable value) {
                                if (engine.getLoadWorker().getState() == FAILED) {
                                    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                                        @Override public void run() {
                                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
                                                    panel,
                                                    (value != null) ?
                                                    engine.getLocation() + "\n" + value.getMessage() :
                                                    engine.getLocation() + "\nUnexpected error.",
                                                    "Loading error...",
                                                    JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                                        }
                                    });
                                }
                            }
                        });

                jfxPanel.setScene(new Scene(view));
            }
        });
    }

    public void loadURL(final String url) {
        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override public void run() {
                String tmp = toURL(url);

                if (tmp == null) {
                    tmp = toURL("http://" + url);
                }

                engine.load(tmp);
            }
        });
    }

    private static String toURL(String str) {
        try {
            return new URL(str).toExternalForm();
        } catch (MalformedURLException exception) {
                return null;
        }
    }

    @Override public void run() {

        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1024, 600));
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        initComponents();

        loadURL("http://oracle.com");

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new SimpleSwingBrowser());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[How to setPage() a JEditorPane with a localfile which is outside of the .jar file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4534881/how-to-setpage-a-jeditorpane-with-a-localfile-which-is-outside-of-the-jar-fil)

```
// get location of the code source
URL url = yourpackage.Main.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation();

    try {
        // extract directory from code source url
        String root = (new File(url.toURI())).getParentFile().getPath();
        File doc = new File(root, "test.htm");
        // create htm file contents for testing
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(doc);
        writer.write("<h1>Test</h1>");
        writer.close();
        // open it in the editor
        editor.setPage(doc.toURI().toURL());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Complete example based on one of the answers

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class EditorPane extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String []args) throws IOException {

        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {

            var frame = new EditorPane();
            frame.setVisible(true);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        });
    }

    public EditorPane() {

        initUI();
    }

    private void initUI() {

        try {
            JEditorPane editorpane = new JEditorPane();
            JScrollPane editorScrollPane = new JScrollPane(editorpane);
            editorScrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
            File file = new File("resources/test.html");
            editorpane.setPage(file.toURI().toURL());
            editorpane.setEditable(true);
            add(editorpane);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(this.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE,
                    "Failed to load file", ex);
        }
    }

}
```