# Swing - local images not displaying when JEditorPane loads a local html

Tags: java, swing

I'm writing something which loads a template html document, does some keyword replacement on that, then prints it out.  This works fine, apart from when there are images included in the template.  If I browse to the template .html images display fine (so I guess paths are OK), but they display as empty space in the final output.

Template html is something like:

```
<html>
<body>
<img src="file://c:/temp/my-logo.png" width="50" height="50"/>
[[[some stuff I want to replace]]]
</body>
</html>
```

Simple enough.
And loading this template like so:

```
public void test() {
   JEditorPane text = new JEditorPane("text/html", "default");
   HTMLEditorKit htmlEditorKit = new HTMLEditorKit();
   HTMLDocument htmlDocument = (HTMLDocument)htmlEditorKit.createDefaultDocument();

   text.setEditorKit(htmlEditorKit);
   // read the html template into the JEditorPane's text
   text.read(new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(new File("path to my template html")))), htmlDocument);

   // then do some replacements
   text.setText(magicReplacements(text.getText()));

   text.repaint();
   // and then print job stuff, fire off the job, check if it worked etc...
}
```

The text displays and formats correctly, just images never display.
Can anyone spot what's wrong?

Cheers.

Comment: See also this [Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15052690/230513) and  [*Display images using JEditorPane*](http://www.javaworld.com/javatips/jw-javatip109.html).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the path is wrong.

Instead of `file://c:/temp/my-logo.png` you should try `file:/c:/temp/my-logo.png`

When testing my example, I used both `//c:/` and `/c:/` and the second one worked, where the first one failed.

I was able to get this to work...

[image]

**HTML**

```
<html>
<body>
<img src="file:/c:/backgroundtext.png"/>
[[[some stuff I want to replace]]]
</body>
</html>
```

**Example Code**

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import javax.swing.JEditorPane;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class TestTextPane {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestTextPane();
    }

    public TestTextPane() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                FileReader fr = null;

                try {
                    fr = new FileReader(new File("c:/Test.html"));
                    JEditorPane editor = new JEditorPane();
                    editor.setContentType("text/html");
                    editor.read(fr, "Test");

                    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                    frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                    frame.add(new JScrollPane(editor));
                    frame.pack();
                    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception exp) {
                    exp.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    try {
                        fr.close();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```